# jquery ui - disable today and highlight next 3 days

Tags: jquery-ui

So far I can disable Today's date, but I'm coming up short trying to highlight the next 3 days

```
$( "#someDiv" ).datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function( date ){
        //disable Sundays;
        return [date.getDay() != 0, '']
    },
    /* today is disabled */
    minDate: 1

});
```

... or is there a way to render individual day cells with date info as data attributes or something like that?

Comment: Is this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4NHT/) along the lines of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I see what I missed, thanks. If you make that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `return`, add a condition that will check for the date range you want and add a class to those dates.

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L4NHT/) with the full example. I'm sure this can be improved upon though.

The code and CSS to add a background to the dates when the condition is true (style it how you like):

```
.highlightDay .ui-state-default {
    background: #484;
    color: #FFF;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var newDate = addDays(new Date(), 0);
            var thirdDay = addDays(new Date(), 3);
            return [date.getDay() != 6, 
                // This can probably be improved
                date >= newDate && date <= thirdDay ? "highlightDay" : ""];
        },
        minDate: 1
    });
});

function addDays(theDate, days) {
    return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}
```